# nginx: behavior of Expect: 100-continue with HTTP redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've been facing some issues with nginx and `PUT` redirects:
Let's say I have an HTTP service sitting behind an nginx server (assume HTTP 1.1)

The client does a `PUT /my/api` with `Expect: 100-continue`.
My service is not sending a `100-continue`, but sends a `307` redirect instead, to another endpoint (in this case, S3).
However, `nginx` is for some unknown reason sending a `100-continue` prior to serving the redirect - the client proceeds to upload the whole body to nginx before the redirect is served. This causes the client to effectively transfer the body twice - which isn't great for multi-gigabyte uploads

I am wondering if there is a way to:

- Prevent `nginx` to send `100-continue` unless the service actually does send that.
- Allow requests with arbitrarily large `Content-Length` without having to set `client_max_body_size` to a large value (to avoid `413 Entity too large`).

Since my service is sending redirects only and never sending `100-Continue`, the request body is never supposed to reach nginx. Having to set `client_max_body_size` and waiting for nginx to buffer the whole body just to serve a redirect is quite suboptimal.

I've been able to do that with Apache, but not with nginx. Apache used to have the same behavior before this got fixed: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60330 - wondering if nginx has the same issue

Any pointers appreciated :)

**EDIT 1: Here's a sample setup to reproduce the issue:**

- An nginx listening on port 80, forwarding to localhost on port 9999
- A simple HTTP server listening on port 9999, that always returns redirects on PUTs

1. nginx.conf

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 261120;
worker_shutdown_timeout 10s ;

events {
    multi_accept        on;
    worker_connections  16384;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
 server { 
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend;
  keepalive_timeout  75s;
  keepalive_requests 100;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999/;
  }
 }
}
```

I'm running the above with

```
docker run --rm --name nginx --net=host -v /path/to/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx:1.21.1
```

2. Simple python3 HTTP server.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Redirect(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_PUT(self):
       self.send_response(307)
       self.send_header('Location', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/test')
       self.end_headers()

HTTPServer(("", 9999), Redirect).serve_forever()
```

**Test results:**

- Uploading directly to the python server works as expected. The python server does not send a `100-continue` on PUTs - it will directly send a 307 redirect before seeing the body.

```
$ curl -sv -L -X PUT -T /some/very/large/file 127.0.0.1:9999/test
> PUT /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 531202949
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 307 Temporary Redirect
< Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.9.2
< Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 10:16:44 GMT
< Location: https://s3.amazonaws.com/test
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/test'
*   Trying 52.216.129.157:443...
* Connected to s3.amazonaws.com (52.216.129.157) port 443 (#1)
> PUT /test HTTP/1.0
> Host: s3.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 531202949
>
```

- Doing the same thing through nginx fails with `413 Entity too large` - even though the body should not go through nginx.
- After adding `client_max_body_size 1G;` to the config, the result is different, except nginx tries to buffer the whole body:

```
$ curl -sv -L -X PUT -T /some/very/large/file 127.0.0.1:80/test
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 531202949
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [65536 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx/1.21.1
< Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 10:22:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 157
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{ [157 bytes data]
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how nginx sends a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`
With this simple python server, the request subsequently fails because the python server closes the connection right after serving the redirect, which causes nginx to serve the 502 due to a broken pipe:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2021:10:22:08 +0000] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
2021/07/15 10:22:08 [error] 31#31: *1 writev() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: frontend, request: "PUT /test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9999/test", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

So as far as I can see, this seems exactly like the following Apache issue https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60330 (which is now addressed in newer versions). I am not sure how to circumvent this with nginx

Comment: Please share your NGINX configuration. I will have a look on it and make some suggestions to work arround this issues.

Comment: @TimoStark just saw your message. Thanks so much for lending a hand, very appreciated :) I have edited my post with nginx configuration and test setup.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution here?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth sorry just saw this. The above person did not respond - I think I ended up finding one config to try, but never got around to it. We lived with the double-buffering for a while, then we eventually didn't need that nginx server anymore. I'd be interested to know if you found something though.

Comment: No, we had to change our integration to handle this header on our end @kiv